# Connecting to Win7 (off domain) file share from WinXP (on domain) client

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, file-sharing

I'm trying to connect a Windows XP, domain-connected laptop to my server's file share.

The server is running Windows 7 Professional and is not on the domain. It is also behind a router (whose hostname is different than the computer name).

Other Windows 7 machines can connect to the server just fine. But, the Windows XP machine throws an error "A duplicate name exists on the network." Two different XP machines have done this.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the workgroup name of the laptop, and is it the same of any machine on the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the IP instead of the server name: "Net Use T: \\a.b.c.d\Share /User:User password"